# curl shows as installed and enabled, but throwing undefined function errors when executed in php

Tags: php, centos7, php-curl

Running on Centos 7 system. phpinfo() says curl is enabled, but when I run this code:

```
<?php
// API
$url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings';

// Create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);
?>
```

I get error: PHP Fatal error:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  curl_init()

If I try to install it says it's already installed:

```
yum install php-curl 
Package php-common-8.1.14-1.el7.remi.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

All out of answers.  What can I try from here?  Why is curl not executing?

```
php --version
PHP 8.1.14 (cli) (built: Jan  4 2023 06:45:14) (NTS gcc x86_64)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.1.14, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v8.1.14, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies

phpinfo();
cURL support    enabled 
cURL Information    7.29.0 

php -i | grep "curl"
/etc/php.d/20-curl.ini,
curl
curl.cainfo => no value => no value
```

In /etc/php.d/20-curl.ini:

extension=curl.so

```
yum list *curl*

Installed Packages
curl.x86_64                                        7.29.0-59.el7_9.1                       installed 
libcurl.x86_64                                     7.29.0-59.el7_9.1                       installed 
libcurl-devel.x86_64                               7.29.0-59.el7_9.1                       installed 
python-pycurl.x86_64                               7.19.0-19.el7                           @base     
Available Packages
collectd-curl.x86_64                               5.8.1-1.el7                             epel      
collectd-curl_json.x86_64                          5.8.1-1.el7                             epel      
collectd-curl_xml.x86_64                           5.8.1-1.el7                             epel      
curlftpfs.x86_64                                   0.9.2-14.el7                            epel      
flickcurl.x86_64                                   1.25-2.el7.nux                          nux-dextopflickcurl-debuginfo.x86_64                         1.25-2.el7.nux                          nux-dextopflickcurl-devel.x86_64                             1.25-2.el7.nux                          nux-dextopfuse-curlftpfs.x86_64                              0.9.1-1.el6.rf                          rpmforge  
libcurl.i686                                       7.29.0-59.el7_9.1                       updates   
libcurl-devel.i686                                 7.29.0-59.el7_9.1                       updates   
nbdkit-plugin-curl.x86_64                          1.2.7-2.el7                             epel      
ocaml-curl.x86_64                                  0.7.5-3.el7                             epel      
ocaml-curl-devel.x86_64                            0.7.5-3.el7                             epel      
perl-WWW-Curl.x86_64                               4.15-13.el7                             base      
php-pear-Net-Curl.noarch                           1.2.5-10.el7                            epel      
python34-pycurl.x86_64                             7.43.0-7.el7                            epel      
python36-pycurl.x86_64                             7.43.0-7.el7                            epel      
uwsgi-alarm-curl.x86_64                            2.0.18-8.el7                            epel      
uwsgi-plugin-curl-cron.x86_64                      2.0.18-8.el7                            epel
```

Comment: _"phpinfo() says curl is enabled"_ - executed from within your script? Or from a different context such as CLI - which might use a different php.ini?

Comment: php -i from command line:

curl
cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.29.0

Answer (score 0):

I spent an hour working with ChatGPT3 on trying to resolve this.  I can't say that the AI actually resolved it, but early in the session it did say this:

> The PHP script you are trying to run is not using the correct PHP
> version. Make sure that you are running the script with the correct
> PHP version that has cURL extension installed.
>
> The PHP script is being run by a user that does not have access to the
> cURL extension. Try running the script with a different user or set
> the correct permissions on the script.
>
> The PHP script may have some syntax errors, which is causing the
> curl_init() function to not be recognized. Verify that your script
> does not contain any syntax errors.
>
> The PHP script may have been corrupted during upload or download. Try
> re-uploading or re-downloading the script and make sure it is not
> corrupted.
>
> There could be a problem with the installed version of curl. Try to
> update the curl version and see if that resolves the issue.

Corruption of the file turned out to be the culprit.  In any event, the steps it took me through to narrow down the issue eventually helped me to resolve it.  I really can't recommend it enough if you're stuck and can't seem to get any responses here, you may want to try: https://chat.openai.com/chat

FYI, the full troubleshooting conversation I had with the AI is here: https://sharegpt.com/c/GJVQs0n

At any rate, after exhaustively verifying that curl was installed and enabled in php and apache was calling the correct php version, I finally realized the problem was in the code itself.  Not the syntax, but apparently there were invisible characters in the code that were causing the error.  After re-entering the same code, it worked.

```
<?php
// API
$url = 'https://api.openai.com/v1/embeddings';

// Create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init($url);
?>
```

If anyone knows of a way to detect these characters in a text file, please leave that info in the comments.  Thanks!